# Deploy existing Java web application on Google App engine or Amazon AWS

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

We have a Java web application developed locally without using any GAE components / AWS components (GAE/AWS SDK etc.,).

We used  the following technologies: Java, Spring framework, MySQL Database, Hibernate ORM, Jersy REST library, Tomcat web server.

Our application is up & running fine on our local server.

Now my question is

1. If I deploy the existing WAR to Google App Engine/ Amazon AWS will it start working right away OR Do I have to make extra changes to my code and deploy new WAR file in order to make it working on Google App Engine / Amazon AWS?
2. If I want to start a new java web project(using same configuration I mentioned above) that will eventually run on Google App Engine / Amazon AWS, What is the best strategy:
   Should I start my development using Google App Engine / Amazon AWS from the beginning ? or just deploy when everything is done?

EDIT : I just wanted to know about GAE and/or AWS in general.

Comment: Well which is it, GAE or AWS?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I want to know about both  GAE & AWS :)

Comment: Well in that case you have about multiple questions in one here, not to mention they are about *completely* different services. It might be hard to find someone who knows enough about both to be able to answer this.

Comment: ok then GAE and/or AWS :)

Comment: lots of people here know about both but your question is invalid for multiple reasons. Write a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Incude code: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302091/2213940.

Comment: @ZigMandel thanks for the suggestion. I edited my question. may be it makes sense now

Comment: still invalid. read the faq. s.o. is not for recomendations. your question is not about coding and is super broad.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Google Computer Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) is more suited if you rely on a relational database. Google app engine uses a NoSQL datastore that is not compatible with your relational scheme.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Just for confirmation : "deploying my existing WAR file as it is on "Google Compute Engine" works fine". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: not so. google appengine can use sql as well just fine.

Comment: @chakra You can't 'just deploy' your WAR file to GCE.  GCE just gives you a raw VM environment, so you will first need to setup your HTTP server (e.g. Tomcat), database, etc.  App Engine is a PaaS that does allow you to 'just deploy a WAR' (and supports Cloud SQL), but to get the most out of App Engine, you should write *for* it and try not to weigh your app down with heavy frameworks.

Comment: @tx802 Thank you very much for the clarification.